# How can I generate an XML Web Services proxy class from WCF

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I am going to have to interoperate with some WCF classes from an ASP.NET 2.0 web application.  What tools exist that I can use to generate a proxy class that is compatible with classic XML Web Services?  AFAIK, the WCF endpoints are using the basic HTTPS binding.

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF was introduced in .net 3.0, so you cannot use WCF from .net 2.0.

However a WCF service with basichttpbinding will work in the same way as a classic xml web service.